# How do I characterise the relationship between one variable and many other variables for a complex socio-technical problem?

Tags: correlation, multivariate-analysis, interaction

I am doing a PhD on a socio-technical problem – this is a building physics problem, where I am trying to determine the relationship between one variable (x) which affects a number (up to 20 other) of other variables (a, b, c etc).

I have calculated x, which can be characterized as both discrete and continuous. All the other variables (a, b, c etc) are continuous. The relationships are complex, as one key influencer over all variables is (unpredictable) human behaviour, and this behaviour can be seasonal.

Due to the seasonal nature of the behaviour, I will likely subset the data based on the seasons and then start to investigate the relationships.

What are the different available methods and techniques for determining the relationship between one variable (x) and a number of other variables (a,b,c)?

I am aware of the following possible methods, but interested in any comments/observations and if there are any more that i should also consider…

1. Multiple linear (continuous dependent variable) regression. Must
   have linear relation between dependent and independent variables.
2. Polynomial regression. Nonlinear.
3. Logistic regression. Discrete dependent variable.
4. Correlation. However, this is only for one variable vs another?

Thank you for any advice.

**Edit 16.08.2021**

My project is specifically looking at 'The relationship between ventilation practices, indoor air quality, noise and overheating, and their impact on health.' [3-minute video on my project here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tmw8Mx6XRAU).

Variable x is ventilation, which can be expressed as both a discrete variable (ventilation practices, window open for example) and as a continuous variable (air exchange rate).

Other variables are (a,b,c etc): temperature, relative humidity, carbon monoxide, carbon dioxide, PM1, PM2.5, PM10, (total) volatile organic compounds, noise, nitrogen dioxide. These are all continuous (measurements).

A side note, is that I can also express the above variables as a rate of decay (for periods of decay).

The relationships here are complex, as human behaviour is the main driving 'force' behind ventilation, by opening and closing windows for example. But human behaviour is also the main driver for the other variables - cooking for example can produce CO, CO2, NO2, VOC, PM etc. Vacuuming, burning candles, heating home, bathing etc all produce pollutants.

My data comprises of 5 minute time-series data for all the variables above.

But...the hypothesis is that there is a relationship between ventilation and the other variables (or the rate of decay of the other variables). So, I am looking at different ways to investigate this relationship in a number of big datasets (using Python). I am looking for advice on different methods for investigating this.

Comment: Hi, this is question is unclear for me. Could you provide more information? At first, it looks like you have a single predictor (X) and several outcomes (a,b,c, etc.) (What is X? How can it be both discrete and continuous? Is this a coding decision?) Then you talk about human behavior as a predictor (I guess that is what you mean by *influencer*, is this your X or a different variable?) over all other variables. So, do you have several predictors and outcomes? If you have a single predictor and several outcomes (as you stated), do you want to estimate the relationships simultaneously?

Comment: Like @T.E.G. I can't follow this. I wonder whether your "affects" is the wrong way round, so that what you call X is really the outcome or response you care about. There is no great virtue in abstraction here. Telling us what some of the variables are would help make this problem more concrete, even for people outside your field. Not trying to be flippant, but as it stands "most of statistics might be relevant here" would be a fair if unhelpful answer.

Comment: @T.E.G. I have added in more information about my project and the variables - I have explained how x can be expressed as both continuous and discrete. I think ventilation is the predictor and the other variables (or rate of decay of) is the outcome - i may have this the wrong way? It is important that I can estimate the relationships simultaneously.

Comment: @NickCox thanks for the comments. I have added much more information, including a link to a 3-minute video about the project. I hope this clarifies.

Comment: A point of personal principle is that questions here should be self-contained, and not dependent on linked material, so (sorry) I won't watch a video.  But it seems clearer to me that ventilation is the outcome. For predicting window open or not, I would recommend logit (logistic) regression. For predicting exchange rate, I would recommend some flavour of regresssion, but much depends on (e.g.) whether there are zeros and whether exchange rate is best thought of on some transformed scale.

Comment: There is in principle scope for some physically-based or physically informed model that uses the time series information.

Comment: Thanks @NickCox I do not know what a physically-based/informed model means. Does this mean that I can use a theoretical framework for this relationship from the literature to constrain the model or inform it somehow?

Comment: I don't know what it would like. But there is surely physics, or engineering, to do with your problem and it may or may not inform your analysis. It sounds, frankly, as if you are way out of your depth. Are you a student learning statistics or a student in another field using statistics or a researcher working on a paper or report?  We (I) can't write a prescription for an entire analysis in comments, even if I were an expert on the set-up.

Comment: @NickCox I am a physicist doing a PhD on this problem. There certainly is both physics and engineering to inform the analysis and interpretation. I am indeed out of my depth in statistics, but confident with physics/engineering/Python.

Comment: Relating ventilation to current conditions only in a regression-type model runs into two problems:  The observations are not independent in so far as there are correlations in time. If history is relevant, then you may need to add lagged variables.

Answer (score 1):

Correlation is typically what I use to screen for association between variables in a complex system with unknown characteristics.  The correlation matrix is a snapshot which shows the association between all possible pairs of variables.  In addition, I typically use Spearman rank correlation, since it's not-sensitive to outliers and doesn't really require central tendency, i.e., bulk of data in the middle of a histogram.  Pearson correlation, on the other hand, does require central tendency and few outliers in order to be less biased than Spearman.  Pearson correlation, and many hypothesis tests in statistics, assume varying degrees of normality, and therefore a **unimodal** distribution.  If you have **multimodal** distributions among your variables, then Pearson is inapplicable, but Spearman may recover some informativeness.  Spearman can also handle triangular distributions quite well.

For the regression models you listed, you'd have to run all three and then compare fits and significance.  Non-linear may be more promising than linear.  Logistic makes no assumptions about the distribution of the predictors (inputs), so that may be helpful.

You might also consider running PCA (principal component analysis) on the variables, and then plot the first two principal component score vectors (n-tuples) against one another using variable labels to see if variables cluster together.

Last, I would consider unsupervised manifold learning to reduce dimensionality and look for patterns among variables (or objects with the data transposed) using e.g. crisp K-means cluster, fuzzy-K-means cluster, diffusion maps, self-organizing maps, localized linear embeddings, Laplacian eigenmaps, locally preserved projections, unsupervised artificial neural networks, stochastic neighbor embedding,  Sammon mapping, non-negative matrix factorization, classic multidimensional scaling, non-metric multidimensional scaling, unsupervised neural gas, Gaussian mixture models, unsupervised random forests, kernel distance-based PCA, kernel Gaussian radial basis function PCA, kernel Tanimoto distance-based PCA, and hierarchical cluster analysis.

The ROI will be greater if you first focus on knowledge discovery through pattern recognition among objects and features.  The key point about non-linear manifold learning methods is that you will always be reducing dimensionality to make 2D and 3D plots of the major 2 or 3 dimensions obtained from the various procedures.  Clustering among objects or features may become apparent with several of the manifold learning approaches.

Comment: This includes some bizarre ideas -- e..g. that Pearson requires "central tendency" and is inapplicable with multimodal distributions. Pearson correlation measures how far relationships are linear;  the nature of the marginal distributions is quite secondary. If the lack of bivariate normality is of concern, use bootstrapping for inference.

Comment: Thanks @Nick Cox, biggest concern is that correlation is hinged to linear association, since the question does mention possibility of non-linearity.

Comment: Thanks, @user0123456789 I have added a bunch more information to the original post. Hopefully, this gives the necessary context.